# Italic tags are showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<span class="fc-event-title" style="background-color:#5E37AD;border-color:#5E37AD">1.test fred 5 &lt;i&gt;(9.5h)&lt;/i&gt;</span>
```

and I see it like this:
[image]

I cannot change the span tag, that is part of fullcalendar. What could I do to see italics rather than the tag itself?

Thanks

Comment: Where does the data come from? You could unescape it on the server side... Be careful with these, dealing with such might open up security holes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
1.test fred 5 &lt;i&gt;(9.5h)&lt;/i&gt;
```

To this:

```
1.test fred 5 <i>(9.5h)</i>
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @donderpiet's answer, `&lt;` and `&gt;` are encoded versions of < and >.

So if you have `<div>hey</div>` in your code it will be rendered as `hey`, but if you encode the greater/less than signs like so: `&lt;div&gt;hey&lt;/div&gt;` it will be rendered as `<div>hey</div>`.

Hope that makes sense.

UPDATE

Based on your comment you will want the [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx) or [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx) functions.

Comment: How would I escape these in  a .Net C# string

Comment: Decode works but I think the span ruins it. It still renders as a tag.